# How i can import data from parse.com service in my own a mongodb database?

Tags: parse-platform, nosql

As you know, parse.com will be closed.

I made export  of all collections. 
Now i have the many dumps of collections.

Collections name like:

**_User**

**AppParentCompany**

It's normal tables name, but between this files i have relations, a relation contained in the next file:

**_Join:parentCompanies:_User.json**

Latest file name i understand like:

1. *_Join* - is relations
2. *parentCompany* - it's column
3. *_User* - a collection containing parentCompany column

Based on this, i have next questions:

How i can import this relations into a database?

What name will be for this collection of relation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Migrating-an-Existing-Parse-App

Prepare mongodb database connection string first.

1. Go to Parse your project's App Settings > General.
2. Find App Management > Migrate to external database. Press Migrate button.
3. Enter your database connection string, it will start with mongodb://...
4. Then press Begin the migration.

Then Parse will do the rest for you.

P.S. If you are using mongolab, go the web browser, into your database, then you can find _Join:xxx:xxx,​​​​​​ _SCHEMA and more in Collections.